# How to replace empty string with some constant value through extension?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am adding an extension for replacing empty string with a constant value like:

```
extension String {
    func checkIfEmpty() -> String {
        return self.isEmpty ? "--------":self
    }
}
```

and also tried the following:

```
extension String {
    var checkIfEmpty: String {
        return self.isEmpty ? "--------":self
    }
}
```

using it as:

```
var string1 = ""
var string2 = "Not empty"

print("\(string1.checkIfEmpty)")
print("\(string2.checkIfEmpty)")
print("\(string1.checkIfEmpty())")
print("\(string2.checkIfEmpty())")
```

but none of them are working. The error says:

> Value of type 'String' has no member 'checkIfEmpty'

I'm using iOS 11, Swift 4 and Xcode Version 9.2.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure that your extension is available from the class you're trying to use it in?

Comment: yes, I am sure because I am using other extensions

Comment: Try cleaning your project and building it again then.

Comment: Use extension outside your class viewController :UIViewController {} then your error will gone

Comment: thanks. I was calling it in a wrong target

Comment: welcome @Chowdhury Md Rajib Sarwar

Answer (score 0):

use

```
extension String {
    func checkIfEmpty() -> String {
        return self.isEmpty ? "--------":self
    }
}
```

and call it like so (notice the `()` ):

```
print("\(string1.checkIfEmpty())")
print("\(string2.checkIfEmpty())")
```

Comment: yeah, I know but that's not the problem.

Comment: What error? same as Value of type 'String' has no member 'checkIfEmpty' ?

Comment: can you try this answer in a playground on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly okay. I was trying it in another target that's why having problem.